# Magento Paypal standard payment return url issue

Tags: php, magento, paypal

I am using Paypal standard payment module on my magento site. i can complete check out process successfully. after completing order it display paypal success page with order complete status and remain on paypal success page. but i want to return it back on my site after complete order. without changing on paypal please tell me which code i have to change. Thanks in advance for help.

Answer (score 0):

Automatic redirect will not work without enabling `Auto Return` feature in paypal website.

To turn on Auto Return:

- Log in to your PayPal account at https://www.paypal.com.
- The My Account Overview page appears.
- Click the Profile subtab.
- The Profile Summary page appears.
- Under the Selling Preferences column, click the Website Payment Preferences link. 
  The Website Payment Preferences page appears, as shown below.
- Under Auto Return for Website Payments, click the On radio button to enable Auto Return.
- In the Return URL field, enter the URL to which you want your payers redirected after they        complete their payments.

Scroll to the bottom of the page, and click the Save button.

**Note**: Auto Return will not work with Credit card Payments, only works only when the payment is made through PayPal account.

Comment: Hello, is it possible paypal checkout process using iframe ?

Comment: It is possible, use HSS or Payflow - layout C/D
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/products/website-payments-pro-hosted-solution/

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/products/payflow-gateway/

Comment: do you have guide how to install it in magento ?

Comment: http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/setting-up-paypal-payflow-link

Comment: I cant see pyapal payflow in my magento payment methods. how can i add there.

Comment: From the Admin panel, select System > Configuration.
In the Configuration panel on the left, under Sales, select Payment Methods.
In the Merchant Location section, select the Merchant Country where your business is located.
Under PayPal Payment Gateways, in the PayPal Payflow Link section, click the Configure button.

if you follow the above steps, still dint see payflow, then contact magento